# Cambiar a factor una variable con condiciones

Tags: r

Amigos buenas noches como puedo cambiar una variable que tengo con 0 y 1.
La condici[on deberia ser si es 0 es nacional y si es 1 es extranjera?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es una base de datos importada de SPSS que tiene niveles preasignados puedes usar el paquete `labelled` que combinada con `dplyr` reconoce los valores preasignados.

`misdatos_spss %>% mutate_if(is.labelled, to_factor)`

Comment: Mario Alberto quiero hacerlo totalmente en R, te agradezco de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion `ifelse`, p.e.

```
> v<-sample(0:1,10,replace=T)
> v
 [1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
> f<-ifelse(v,"nacional","extranjera")
> f<-factor(f,levels=c("nacional","extranjera"))
> f
 [1] nacional   extranjera nacional   extranjera extranjera extranjera
 [7] extranjera extranjera extranjera nacional
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a validarlo en mis datos

Comment: Efectivamente me fue de mucha ayuda este código, mil gracias.

Comment: @ROBERTOESPINOZA, si la pregunta te ha ayudado, te pido que consideres aceptarla y/o votarla positivamente. Saludos